# How do I install MegaRAID Storage Manager properly?

Tags: esxi, hardware-raid

OK, so installing it seems straightforward enough, but making it work afterwards is so awkward I must've done something wrong. It appears that this problem has nothing to do with ESXi or the RAID hardware, since the app doesn't even get that far, so I'm not sure which support category this falls under on LSI's own site.

We have a Supermicro machine with a pair of LSI MegaRAID 8888ELP cards in it. All the hardware and ESXi 4.1 itself are working perfectly. LSI's MSM manual claims support for ESXi via Common Information Model (CIM) providers, by installing the entire product on another machine on the same network as the ESXi host (preferably a VM running on it), because the monitoring framework cannot be installed directly on the ESXi host.

So I've configured a clean Win2003SP2 VM and done a complete install of the Storage Manager as indicated by its manual. It sets up a GUI tool and two services: a Framework service and an MRMonitor service.

The Framework service is running, but the MRMonitor one terminates as soon as I start it. The manual seems to suggest that the GUI tool connects to this service in order to manage ESXi machines on the same network. When pointed to the VM's IP the GUI tool complains that the 'server may be down or server not installed in the host system'.

MSM version is 8.17-20 (or 8.10.0400, or MegaRAID release 4.6, depending on where you look). We've tried running it on Win7, Win2003SP2, and Ubuntu 10.10, and all have the same issue. The firewall is not interfering, because in every case it was turned off.

The contents of MonitorDbg.log on the Win7 machine follows. The other two OSes resulted in pretty much the same log:

```
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Info) .\MonitorWinService.cpp 88 : Startup() - entering
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\message_queue\message_queue.cpp 11 : Message queue constructor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\message_queue\message_queue.cpp 14 : Message queue constructor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\message_queue\message_queue.cpp 17 : Message queue constructor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\messaging.cpp 12 : creating consumer thread class
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\messaging.cpp 68 : constructing a messaging framework
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 131 : Initializing listener object
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 56 : SSL Library Initialized
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 71 : SSL Context created
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 82 : Found Certificate Chain
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 90 : Found Private Key
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 152 : Port being tried : 49152 49152
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 163 : First do_accept failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 108 : error:02006740:system library:bind:reason(1856)

(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 152 : Port being tried : 49153 49153
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 163 : First do_accept failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 108 : error:20069075:BIO routines:BIO_get_accept_socket:unable to bind socket

(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 152 : Port being tried : 49154 49154
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 163 : First do_accept failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\ssl\SSLFacility.cpp 108 : error:02006740:system library:bind:reason(1856)

(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 152 : Port being tried : 49155 49155
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\listener\listener.cpp 173 : Will listen on port: 49155
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\messaging.cpp 71 : got a listener
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 268 : starting MonitorSSl Constructor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 257 : Framework address is : 192.168.0.88:3071
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 90 : Connecting to Vivaldi framework at - 192.168.0.88:3071
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 95 : my address:192.168.0.88
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 107 : port: 49155
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 108 : port: 49155
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 113 : sending
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\writer\writer.cpp 61 : data sent 616
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\ssl\writer\writer.cpp 83 : read 84 bytes
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 119 : registration sent
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 129 : Monitor Info: IP - 127.0.0.1 Port: 49155 Id: 4
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 321 : SSL initialized
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorSsl.cpp 324 : finished MonitorSSl Constructor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 43 : Parsing
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 46 : C:\Program Files (x86)\MegaRAID Storage Manager\
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\XMLConfigParser.cpp 56 : 9
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\XMLConfigParser.cpp 122 : translating popup
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\..\ConfigData.cpp 30 : adding action popup
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\XMLConfigParser.cpp 122 : translating email
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\..\ConfigData.cpp 30 : adding action email
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\XMLConfigParser.cpp 122 : translating systemlog
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\..\ConfigData.cpp 30 : adding action systemlog
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\XMLConfigParser.cpp 122 : translating vivaldilog
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) ..\..\ConfigData.cpp 30 : adding action vivaldilog
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 3
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 3
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 3
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 3
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 2
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 2
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 2
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 1
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 1
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 0
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Error) c:\monitor\univ_monitor_1.1_dev\app_viva\univ_monitor\config\Global.h 23 : global 0
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 70 : Parsed
(Command Tool)(Error) .\AlertActionPopup.cpp 278 : Error opening file C:\Program Files (x86)\MegaRAID Storage Manager\/MegaMonitor/AlertActionCfg.txt
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionPopup.cpp 55 : AlertAction cfg file is empty - no pending popup events
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\Monitor.cpp 333 : Error - cannot get ctrlId list from StorelibMFI - explore failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\Monitor.cpp 410 : Error - cannot get ctrlId list from StorelibIR - explore failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\Monitor.cpp 462 : Inside getIr2AlertControllerList
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\Monitor.cpp 482 : getIr2AlertControllerList dataProviderId 2
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\Monitor.cpp 488 : Error - cannot get ctrlId list from StorelibIR2 - explore failed
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\Monitor.cpp 154 : Warning - No MFI, IR or IR2 controllers detected
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 251 : In Execute systemlog
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLogger.cpp 31 : Loaded dynamic library AlertStrings 0x003d0000
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 218 : c==theConfig so storeLib generated alert
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 46 : ANS : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><message><data><alertData><id>61442</id><seqNum>0</seqNum><alertDate><dd>10</dd><month>05</month><yyyy>2011</yyyy><hh>15</hh><mm>38</mm><ss>16</ss></alertDate><class>1</class><paramCount>0</paramCount></alertData></data></message>
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\AlertStrings.cpp 90 : in  AlertStrings::parse
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) ..\..\AlertStrings.cpp 97 : Log : 
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 108 : registering
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 110 : registered
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 114 : reporting
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 116 : reported- deregistering
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionSystemLoggerWin.cpp 118 : de-registered
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Fatal) .\MonitorMain.cpp 33 : Error - cannot initialize Monitor
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\Monitor.cpp 277 : Monitor destructor called - deleting elements of alert Controller list
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\Monitor.cpp 298 : Monitor destructor called - deleting alert Controller list
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Info) .\MonitorWinService.cpp 39 : Run() - changing service to STOP
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Info) .\MonitorWinService.cpp 93 : Startup() - returning
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorMainWin.cpp 195 : Before deleting monwinsvc
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\MonitorMainWin.cpp 200 : After deleting monwinsvc
(Vivaldi Monitor)(Debug) .\AlertActionManager.cpp 262 : Deleting AlertAction objects
```

It almost looks like it's complaining about the absence of an LSI device in the local machine, but that surely should not be necessary for managing a remote machine?

Any ideas?